# Counting Rotations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to count the rotation that an object makes on the z axis when the player presses space, and I want to be able to reset it, so I made this code for it.

```
float lastRotation;
float amountRotated = 0;
void Start()
{
    lastRotation = transform.rotation.z;
}
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) {
        amountRotated += Mathf.Abs(transform.rotation.z - lastRotation);
        lastRotation = transform.rotation.z;
        print(amountRotated);
    } else {
        amountRotated = 0f;
        lastRotation = transform.rotation.z;
    }
}
```

But when I run it and rotate the object wile pressing space, it gives me a number close to zero, like 0.012345, then it gives me some weird number, like 9.25E, then keeps giving me numbers like these over and over again. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the script meant to do? I understand you want to ‘count rotations’, but why do you need to count the rotations?

Comment: I want to make the object speed up when it stops rotating depending on how much it rotates.

Comment: Sorry, you want it to speed up while it is rotating? So, the longer you rotate, the faster it will rotate? Is that all?

Comment: No, I want it to keep track of how much it rotated while the player was holding the space bar, and when the player stops holding the space bar, I apply a force to the object, kind of like a powerslide feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not rotating the player, so the `amountRotated` will not increase. We should add a rotate function.

```cs
public float rotSpeed;
float lastRotation;
float amountRotated = 0;
void Start()
{
    lastRotation = transform.rotation.z;
}
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) {
        transform.Rotate(transform.up * rotSpeed);
        amountRotated += Mathf.Abs(transform.rotation.z - lastRotation);
    } else {
        amountRotated = 0f;
    }
    lastRotation = transform.rotation.z;
}
```

This way, `amountRotated` will be increasing because we are changing the rotation. You set `amountRotated` to a - b, where a is the rotation, and b is the lastRotation, so if you didn’t rotate at all, a = b, and a - b = 0.

Comment: I had been rotating the object with a different function, but now instead of giving me some weird number, it gives me a number close to zero, then the actual amount of rotations that I want, and repeats that process. Would you know why the extremely small number keeps popping up? I could also just use it as a failure mechanic hehe.

Comment: @Kit how often does it do it? Like if you put a print statement, does it appear to be random or do the weird numbers and correct number alternate? Do you change the rotation, lastRotation, or amountRotated anywhere else in the script?

Comment: I didn't change anything anywhere else in the script, and the numbers alternate.

Comment: @Kit Did you copy and paste my code? Try doing that, because you may have slightly different code than me. Try it on a different game object that isn’t being affected by any scripts, just to test it.

Comment: C# is weird (:. There is no visible difference, and yet yours works!

Comment: @Kit Glad to Help! ...I probably forgot to mention a line that I removed or something.